# What is that called in set theory that can be used in programming to make set A equal to set B by adding to and subtracting from B the differences?

Tags: set-theory, difference-sets

What is that called in set theory that can be used in programming to make set B equal to set A by (1) adding to set B what set A has but set B does not have, and (2) removing from set B what set A does not have, but set B does have?

I think it's similar to the concept of a symmetric difference, not not alike.

Step (1) would be to add (A-B) to B.

Step (2) would be to subtract (B-A) from B.

I think it could be expressed like this:

B_prime = B + (A-B) - (B-A)

B_prime = B + A - B - B + A

B_prime = - B + A + A

If I call B_prime the resulting state of what was originally B, B_prime should be expressed as the differences between the sets plus the intersection of the sets, like so:

B_prime = (intersection between A and B) + (A-B)

B_prime = (intersection between A and B) + A - B

In code, B_prime would actually be the resulting state of B after the process is complete.

However, I am not able to make the steps I outlined agree with the way I think the expression should be expressed in terms of B_prime. How do I connect the steps I outlined with the way I think the result should be as expressed as B_prime.

Is there a name for the entire process I described? If there is a name for it than it is a likelihood that there is a function in any language that does exactly just that, and I wouldn't need to write my own code to do this.

Comment: When you write "$+$" between two sets: Is that the same as union?

Comment: In set theory, if $A \neq B$ then $A \neq B,$ end of story. You don't "make" one set equal to a different set. In most programming environments, however, A and B would translate to addresses where data structures are stored. The obvious way to make them equal is to copy one data structure into the other data structure's location (possibly after first removing the data structure previously there). Alternatively you use smart pointers and make them both point to the same location to achieve equality.

Comment: In short, $B_\mathrm{prime} = A,$ supported in various programming languages.

Comment: @paw88789 No. I mean to express that I add to the set. So B_prime would be be B added by what is not in B but is in A, and subtracted by what is in B but is not in A. Thus B_prime := B + (A-B) - (B-A). I apologize. I don't remember set notation. I edited the post before I saw your comment. I deleted the part that doesn't seem right as compared to the result I think I should get when I express B_prime in terms of the intersect between A and B added by the difference between A and B as I express as (A-B). I just noticed I called "union" when I was thinking of what actually is an intersection.

Comment: @paw88789 I added back my mathematical expression I wrote of the two steps I outlined that had the + sign that you may have been talking about. I also corrected the "u" sign I used to indicate a "union", which was the word I thought when I was actually thinking of what is correctly called an intersection.

Comment: @DavidK I'm not well versed enough in set theory to be able to apply it to programming. I was hoping thinking about my problem in mathematical terms would help me simplify my code. Your answer is good, but I have to be able to apply it to in programming. I would need to see the specific steps leading to B_prime. The problem I am trying to solve is on stackoverflow at the following link. It would help you understand my problem if you looked at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72504172/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-update-data-on-cloudkit-to-reflect-data-on-a-d

Comment: Set $ B_{prime}:=(B \cup (A \cap B^{\complement})) \cap (B \cap A^{\complement})^{\complement}$. The RHS when solved gives $A$.

Comment: Looking at the linked question, it looks like it actually involves data replication between two devices. This has been done in a lot of ways, from transactional databases to git clones. So you could choose an off-the-shelf solution or you can make your own tuned to your application. One way is to just make sure every change gets sent to both locations, and if you can't send changes to the other location for a while, store them and play them back when you're connected again.